# How to sum up the columns of views table in drupal7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

How do I put a field summary in the footer of my views (Drupal 7) view?

So I am listing user profiles, one of the fields contain an integer value for the amount of products they will order each month.

User1: 45
User2: 45
User3: 30

In the footer of this view, I would like to sum up all the values from the table, so in the bottom of the "amount of products" column I would get the value 120.

How do I best go about doing this? I am new to Drupal but fairly experienced with PHP. I have heard of custom views templates, would that be the way or is there an easier way?

Thanks!

---

Thanks,
I'm running Drupal7 though so yet no luck with that module.

I feel it is something easy I am trying to do here, I am really surprised that this isn't easy to accomplish.

I took a longshot with something like this, but no luck...

```
if (isset($mCount_test)) {

    $mCount_test+=1; //if it is set, add to it
}
else {
    $mCount_test=0; //if this is the first step of the loop, set (create) the variable
}

//print the actual contents
print $fields["title"]->content;

//check if my sum-variable is working... (which it ain't...)
print "[$mCount_test]";
```

I assume it has something to do with variable scope, I haven't had the time to dig down inte how views actually uses these template files.

Would be nice if there were a template file that sort of wraps this fields-template (like page.tpl? Looks like it doesn't 'cause anything I do in that file is a no-show...) where I could set the variable, let this fields-template file add to that variable, and then back in the page.tpl print the end result from that variable at the footer of my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing calculations in Views is not very straightforward, you can try with [Views Calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc) .
Other alternative is getting the view programatically, looping through results and doing the calculation manually.

Comment: Do you mean writing up an SQL query myself, or is there a more automated/friendly way of going about "looping through the results"?